# android click notification bring back the application

Tags: android, notifications, xamarin.android

I want that when the user click on a notification, it brings back the app (instead of create a new instance).

Here is my code (monodroid : in c# but even if you know how to do in android, you may help me).

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,  typeof(MainListProductActivity));
i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.BroughtToFront | ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront); // You need this if starting  the activity from a service
i.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);
i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryLauncher);
context.StartActivity(i);
```

It works, but it bring back me to the MainListProductActivity. I want that the notification bring back me to the last viewed activity. How to do that ?

More : if the app is not started, I want that the app is launched with the default activity (splashscreen for me) with a parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that by launching a DummyActivity which call Finish on OnCreate.
It works well, even if is not the best way to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

DummyActivity is a great solution. I use it too. Just create dummy and put it instead a needed class on Intent creation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DummyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved for me for Xamarin by using:

```
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ResetTaskIfNeeded);
```